# Riemann integral properties

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

I'm having some trouble with the properties of definite integrals, I understand that if $$m\leq f(x)\leq M \;\mathrm{on}\; [a,b] \;\mathrm{then,}\;$$ $$m(b-a)\leq \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx\leq M(b-a)$$ but I don't know how to apply that to these questions that our professor set for us as a past quiz, no need for a detailed answer just wondering how you would approach a question like this (algebraically, geometrically, etc.) Any useful source on this topic?

$$\mathrm{Suppose\;two\;Riemann\;integrable\;functions}\; f,g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \;\mathrm{satisfy}\; m\leq f(x)\leq M \;\mathrm{and}\; m\leq g(x)\leq M \;\mathrm{for\; all\;} x \in [a,b], \;\mathrm{which\; of\; the\; following\; are\; true?}$$

$$\mathrm{if\;} m\cdot M>0 \mathrm{\;then\;} \int_{a}^{b} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\,dx \geq  \left |\frac{m}{M}\right |(b-a)$$

$$\mathrm{if\;} m >0 \mathrm{\;then\;} \int_{a}^{b} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\,dx \leq \frac{M}{m} (b-a)$$

$$\mathrm{if\;} M <0 \mathrm{\;then\;} \int_{a}^{b} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\,dx \leq \frac{M}{m}$$

$$\mathrm{if\;} m\cdot M<0 \mathrm{\;then\;} \int_{a}^{b} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\,dx \mathrm{\;does\;not\;exist}$$

[Problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kg90.jpg)

I know that if the integrand is positive over an interval, the integral is also positive, and the property involving infimums and supremums of functions

Comment: Welcome to the site. Math Stack Exchange is not a "Problem and Solution" site. Kind people here will try to help you by reviewing your own solution, improving your current thoughts, or giving you the right approach and sometimes (maybe often) full solution. So please, consider adding more details to your post including the source of this problem and your own attempt to tackle this problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was just wondering how one would approach a question like this? Maybe just asking for a little pointer as other students couldn't figure these questions out too either and there is no answer from the professor.

Comment: Better if you write out the question here, instead of asking users to chase it offsite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try to find a proof or a counterexample.

**I will do the first problem here**: If $mM>0$ then either $m, M < 0$ or $m, M>0$. In either case $g$ is bounded away from zero and $\frac fg$ is well-defined. In this case $\frac fg$ is also integrable.

If $m, M < 0$ then $f,g < 0$ on the intervall or if $m, M > 0$ then $f, g > 0 $ on the intervall. Thus $\frac fg>0$ and thus $\frac fg = \frac{|f|}{|g|}$.

Now since $|f|\geq |m|$ and $|g|\leq |M|$ we have $\frac{f}{g}\geq \left|\frac mM\right|$. We can integrate that inequality on both sides over the interval $[a,b]$ to get the desired result.

**The last line**: When $mM < 0$ then this means that either $m<0$ and $M>0$ or $m>0$ and $M<0$. Since $m\leq M$ only the first case is possible. And in that case this means that $g$ might become zeros. Thus $\frac fg$ is not always well-defined. But there are cases in which $-5=m<\frac 12\leq f,g\leq M$. Both $f,g$ are positive and their quotient is well-defined and bounded. Thus the integral exists.

Furthermore even if $g$ might be zero at $t\in[a,b]$. $f$ might be such that the discontinuity is bounded (e.g. $f=2g$). In this case, even though $\frac fg$ is not well defined on the interval, we could get a continuous extension here or use the fact that $\frac fg$ can be undefined at finitely many points on the interval $[a,b]$.

This is just elementary arguing and should be straight-forward.

Comment: Thank you! will do